# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘Rsenal’

Tags: r, github, namespaces, devtools

I am trying to use this source from github.

```
devtools::source_url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/Rsenal/master/R/bin.R')
```

I could use this and work with it till few hours back. but now it gives me the following error

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘Rsenal’
```

The code is still there in the provided url. I did re run the following two commands but still not working.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
```

What  should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Load the package properly, just like [it tells you](https://github.com/brooksandrew/Rsenal/): install devtools (if it's not already) with `install.packages('devtools')`, then install Rsenal with `devtools::install_github('brooksandrew/Rsenal')`, then load it with `library(Rsenal)`.

Comment: I'm looking at the source_url script and it doesn't actually use `Rsenal` anywhere in the code explicitly, and I am able to load it fine using `devtools::source_url`. Three functions appear in my workspace: `binCat`, `depthbin`, and `roundCut`. Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: For me this error message is not reproducible. 
I can use all functions provided by the script. There is a package called [Rsenal](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/tree/master/R).
use `rm(list = ls(all=TRUE))` to clean your environment and then try again!

Comment: thanks alistaire, I wonder how I managed to run this for the past few days without, the install_github command. it worked again after installing but gave me a bunch of warnings like "Warning: replacing previous import 'arules::union' by 'igraph::union' when loading 'Rsenal". Thank u very much for your kind help

Comment: twitch_city, hey i'm sorry i had to use both devtools::source_url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/Rsenal/master/R/bin.R')
devtools::source_url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/Rsenal/master/R/rules2df.R') , so i only used the first command to ask the question

Comment: thanks for the suggestion J_F

Comment: Interesting... Looking at the second script, I still see no reference to the `Rsenal` package - only to `arules`. Perhaps `Rsenal` was loaded by accident and is masking a function from another package? edit: Derp, didn't realize these functions lived *inside* Rsenal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is arising because you are sourcing functions that live inside a package, that is meant to be distributed as a package.

Instead of using `devtools::source_url()`, try this:

```
devtools::install_github('brooksandrew/Rsenal')
library("Rsenal")
```

Once the package is properly installed, all of the primary functions (such as `binCat()`) should be available for use.

I believe you ran into this error because some functions within the package probably depend on others that are not found within the two files you manually sourced.  So when those lines are executed, R looks for the `Rsenal` package file and does not find them.

Further troubleshooting would require a reproducible example.